# Pentaho CDE how to display parameter value from select component

Tags: pentaho, dashboard

I'm very new in Pentaho CDE and I needs to display parameter's value as result of "select component".
I have a parameter name "selectedYear" that I needs to show parameter's value in column name "selectedYear_value".
I use "Text component" name "TC1" with expression :

> function() {return Dashboards.getParameterValue("selectedYear");}

but the result is "Error processing component (TC1)".

Select Component :

[image: Select Component]

Text Component :

[image: Text Component]

Please help...

Regards,
Boy_Rc

Answer (score -1):

You need to put a name for the function:

```
function fun() {return Dashboards.getParameterValue("selectedYear");}
```